# SSAS - Cannot create relationships due to dupicate column entries

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I am currently building a tabular cube in SSAS, however I'm having issues when creating relationships.

I have 3 tables

- Master
- Supplier
- Customer

In the master table I have a list of unique IDs, these ID's appear in the other 2 tables (there can be duplicate records for the ID in the Supplier and Customer table).

What I'm tring to do is create a relationship between the Master table and the Supplier and Customer table. **One to Many**. But SSAS gives me an error **The relationship cannot be created because each column contains duplicate values. Select at least one column that contains only unique values.**

Any advise would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message it seems to be there are some duplicate values in the master table within the column that is being selected for relationship.